# How to create a non uniform pressure load in MSC Patran

Tags: structural-engineering, finite-element-method, nastran

I need to simulate an external pressure load that varies sinusoidally along a circular arc. The sinusoidal variation is with arc length.

I know how to create a uniform pressure load in Patran but do not know how to create a non uniform pressure load. I can't seem to find any guides, tutorials or articles on it either.

If anyone knows how to do this or has a useful guide they could link, your help will be greatly appreciated.

I am using MSC Nastran/Patran student version 2017.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it is with fields. In this specific case I had to set up two additional coordinate systems. These were cylindrical coordinate systems the were located at the centre of the two circular arcs which defined the surfaces to which the pressure was applied. 
The two fields were then defined for in their respective coordinate frame using a PCL function.

The pressure is then applied like a normal constant pressure but the input is the field and not some static value.

I'm sorry I don't have any screenshots to better illustrate this but I hope it helps someone.